# call method in Iron-Router RouteController from Template.tmpl.helpers() not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to push new data on to my `clients` array each time the `loadMoreClients` method is called. The publication is expecting this `back_to` parameter and knows how to handle it.  My problem is that I can't seem to call these methods from my Template helpers .

I logged `Iron` and `Iron.controller` to the console and both of those exist and are showing me what I expected to see.  I just can't seem to find current docs or examples of how to access `Iron.controller()` methods/properties from my Template helpers

Here is my RouteController code:

```
ClientController = ApplicationController.extend({
action : function(){
    this.render(Router.current().route.getName())
},

data : function(){
    if( this.params._id ){
        return Clients.findOne({ _id:this.params._id })
    }
},

waitOn : function(){
    return [
        Meteor.subscribe('directory'),
        Meteor.subscribe('clients')
    ]
},

loadMoreClients : function(){
    this.months_back += 3
    this.back_to = moment().subtract(this.months_back,'months').startOf('day')
    this.clients.push(Meteor.subscribe('clients', {back_to:this.back_to, skip:this.clients.length}))
},

loadAllClients : function(){
    this.clients.push(Meteor.subscribe('clients', {back_to:this.start_of_time, skip:this.clients.length}))
},

// we'll use these properties to 'load more' client data
clients : [],
back_to : moment().subtract(3,'months').startOf('day'),
months_back : 3,
start_of_time : moment(new Date(0))
})
```

Here is my helpers code:

```
Template.client_list.helpers({
clients : function(){
    var clients = []
    Iron.controller().clients.forEach(function(client){
        // ... some stuff here...
        clients.push(client)
    })

    return clients
},

earliestClientLoaded : function(){
    var controller = Iron.controller()
    return controller.clients[controller.clients.length - 1].createdAt
}
})

Template.client_list.events({
'click .btn-load-more' : function(e){
    e.preventDefault()

    Iron.controller().loadMoreClients()
},

'click .btn-load-all' : function(e){
    e.preventDefault()

    Iron.controller().loadAllClients()
}
})
```

I'm getting `undefined function` errors on my `Iron.controller()` calls to `loadMoreClients` and `loadAllClients` methods.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the approach to this problem by simply updating the subscription to subscribe to posts earlier than the currently loaded date.

It is working, although seems like there should be a better way than having to `waitOn` the subscription when I want to load more.